# Can I find a way to build interactive animation using Python

Tags: python, animation, interactive

I'm not very good in Python and just used several times before. I used PYQT and python to make an interface for controlling out-side devises.

I'm wondering whether Python can make an interactive animation something like Flash produces. I searched and found some suggestions: HTML5, Pygame and Tkinter. I have no idea about how those things work with Python.

Does someone can give some advises? Thank you!

Comment: If you're using PyQt5 : you can check some examples about animations here [pyqt5](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/tree/master/examples/animation) or [pyqt4](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples/animation).
Concerning html5, you can use QtWebKit to setup HTML5 pages, CSS and JS.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion Pygame the best library in Python3. You can do all things that you want, but you need to work in the hard-way, control main_loop, work with messed up classes and perhaps needs some OpenGL basic functions.

Tkinter is a good lib to make softwares, but to work with graphics is badly. Is easy, have a lot of tutorials in net, you don't need to work directly to main_loop... But is limited, in some step you will stuck and take the double of time to figure out.

You should be use Pygame or Pyglet (Similar to pygame, but still updated and more organizated -- doens't have much tutorials on net, so if you are begginer don't try this before pygame).

Comment: Thank you very much. If I can not find other solution, I'll stick on Pygame. Thanks.